# Nginx proxy server redirects on 302 Found status code

Tags: http, nginx, proxy

I have two backend servers on different ports and I'm using nginx to proxy requests from frontend.

my simple nginx config:

```
server {
   listen 8085;
   server_name localhost;

location /one {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:7784;
}

location /two {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:7785;
}
```

The problem is When UI request url for ex. localhost:8085/one?cmd=EVENT...

Then nginx answers 302 Found and redirects to localhost:8085/one/?cmd=EVENT... - it is added one more slash after "one" and in addition lost Request Payload params.

How can I change config to answer with original url without redirecting? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the backslash at the end of location and proxy_pass ?

```
server {
   listen 8085;
   server_name localhost;

location /one/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:7784/;
}

location /two/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:7785/;
}
```